# JBoss 5 - Wildfly 10.1 upgrade, only displaying static HTML after deployment

Tags: java, jsp, server, jboss, wildfly

What we have done:

- Currently running JBOSS 5 application
- Need to upgrade to Wildfly 10
- Deployed JDBC driver
- Connected to data source (IBM Maximo Database)
- Deployed War files
- All has been done successfully to best of our understanding (in command line no error when running standalone.bat just warnings.

Problem:

- We can display static HTML pages however our data from our data source cannot be leveraged

Question?

- Cannot share any files as it is confidential business related, where would be the logical first area to check to overcome this issue?

Some references in the log to the JDBC

```
2018-07-30 13:35:10,047 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
2018-07-30 13:35:10,067 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
2018-07-30 13:35:10,103 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.4.0.Final starting
2018-07-30 13:35:16,228 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (version 11.2)
2018-07-30 13:35:16,316 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = ojdbc6.jar
2018-07-30 13:35:10,751 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (version 11.2)
2018-07-30 13:35:19,916 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry jdbc-se2.0.jar in mypath…/WEB-INF/lib/castor-0.9.5.2-xml.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
2018-07-30 13:35:20,185 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry jdbc-se2.0.jar, in mypath…/WEB-INF/lib/castor-0.9.4.1.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
```

Comment: Sounds like your jdbc connection isn’t working. Check your log files (`./standalone/logs` if I remember correctly) or perhaps test your jdbc connections and deployments via the management console.

Comment: ADDED SOME JDBC COMMENTS FROM THE LOG APPRECIATE THE HELP.

Comment: How do i test JDBC connection